# Numpy Documentation

Tags: python, numpy

What happened to http://docs.scipy.org/ ? It has been down for a really long time. What is a recommended documentation source alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say if it is *recommended* but it looks correct - http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.8.1/